# copy a row in one worksheet and paste in another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

this is the code and i don't know what is wrong that it fail ?
i think i couldn't define a range that changes 
the aim is to copy a selected row from one worksheet to the end of another worksheet...row.counts and so on didn't work at all ! i don't know why ...i am using excel2007 and vba version is 6.5 and i don't know if i can upgrade it to better version?this is the code:

```
K = 2
For i = 1 To LastLine
  If Cells(i, 2).Value = longti Then
   Rows(i).Select
   Selection.Copy
   Worksheets("result").Range("A" & "k").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

thank you for help . i don't know if question is clear or not

Comment: Your code is incomplete and but the error is clearly in `"A" & "k"`. This simply concatenates to make it equivalent to the string `"Ak"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Range("A" & "k")` should probably be `.Range("A" & K)` (i.e. lose the quotes around the letter K)

As you have it now, the code is looking for a range with address "Ak" which doesn't make sense. The amended code will look for a range with address "A2" which is probably what you want